# I need to hide content on the weekend

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php

I've got a countdown timer that shows one thing before 2pm and another for after 2pm. I need to now add something else that shows something else on the weekend and hides the first part. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('select_program') == "Yes"): ?> 

    <?php date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); ?>
<div id="countdown">
    <?php

    /* This sets the $time variable to the current hour in the 24 hour clock format */
    $time = date("H");
    /* Set the $timezone variable to become the current timezone */
    $timezone = date("e");

    if ($time >= "8" && $time <= "14") {
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('countdown-products')->toHtml();
    } else

    if ($time >= "15" && $time < "23") {
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('countdown_tomorrow')->toHtml();
    } 
    ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>



<div id="weekendchecker">
    <!--Check for Sat and Sun-->
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('cd_select_program') == "Yes"): ?> 
    <?php
    if(date('D') == 'Sat' || date('D') == 'Sun') { 
      echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('countdownSatSun')->toHtml();
    } 
    ?>
<?php endif ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php   
     date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
     echo $date= date('Y-m-d') ;
     $timestamp = strtotime($date);
     $weekday= date("l", $timestamp );
     $normalized_weekday = strtolower($weekday);
     if (($normalized_weekday == "saturday") || ($normalized_weekday == "sunday")) {
              echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('countdownSatSun')->toHtml();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I hide the top part when this code is rendered on the weekend?

Comment: Please disregard. I got it. Thank you very much for your help.  I just added else if and declared a new variable for hours.

Comment: Glad could help!

Comment: Within those blocks are javascript countdown timers. Is there a simple way to make it stay on Eastern Standard time? I know the PHP will.

Comment: I am not confident that I got your point. But as per my understanding you want to set timezone to EST via javascript. Possible solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206260/how-to-set-date-always-to-eastern-time-regardless-of-users-time-zone